# Database Relationships in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have Author model that looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Author extends Model {
   public $timestamps = false;

   public function role()
   {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Role');
  }
}
```

And Role model that looks like:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model {
   public $timestamps = false;
}
```

My AuthorController.php looks like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Author;

class AuthorController extends Controller
{
  public function index(){
    $role = Author::find(5)->role->pareigos;

    return view('authors', ['role' => $role]);
  }
}
```

But I get error like:

> "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'roles.author_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `roles` where
>   `roles`.`author_id` = 5 and `roles`.`author_id` is not null limit 1)

Where does the author_id even come from?

I have two tables in database, first one is `authors` that has id,firstname,lastname,role_id. Second one is `roles` that has two rows - id and pareigos. So I use this command:

```
$role = Author::find(5)->role->pareigos;
```

To find Author by id (5) and check his role_id in `roles` table and return `pareigos` if the ID's matches.

Don't know if I have described the problem clearly - if not, just let me know I eill add more details.

Comment: Laravel __doesn't know__ by what field your Role and Author tables are connected. So, by defaut `author_id` is used, where `author` is your entity's name and `id` is a common field name.

Comment: @u_mulder how to tell Laravel that? :)

Comment: By the way your table relations is incorrect. `hasOne` describes that `Role` should have `author_id` field. In your case it's vice-versa and I suppose that many users can have same role. So, basically it's a one to many relation, where one is `Role` and many is `Author`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your relationship is setup incorrectly. The table that has the key pointing to another table, belongs to that other table.

```
class Author ... 
{
    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
    }
    ...
```

This will want to look for a `role_id` key on `authors` table.  By default, unless you pass more arguments to override it, Laravel uses the calling function name to decide the name of the foreign key for `belongsTo` relationships.  [ method is named `role`, so it knows to look for `role_id` ... `methodname` + `_id` ]